# Wpf call function of ContentControl view

Tags: c#, wpf

I am pretty new to C# so I am just starting to learn the basics. Right now I have a `ContentControl` inside a Window like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" x:Name="SubView"/>
```

And I configured my resources of the Windows like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="StammdatenViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:StammdatenViewModel}">
        <views:StammdatenView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="AdministrationViewTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:AdministrationViewModel}">
        <views:AdministrationView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

In my Window class I am setting the `DataContext` like this:

```
DataContext = new StammdatenViewModel();
```

Here is the thing I would like to do. I want to disable all the `TextBoxes` inside the `ContentControl`. I thought about adding a function to my `StammdatenView.xaml.cs` class (which is the class of my subview), then firing the event from the Window somehow. Though I would need access to the function inside the subview. Is that somehow possible and if yes how? Or would anyone suggest a different approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or would anyone suggest a different approach?

Yes. You should bind the `IsEnabled` property of each `TextBox` in the `StammdatenView` to a boolean property of the `StammdatenViewModel`. 
You can then disable the `TextBoxes` by setting the source property in the view model class. This is one of the key aspects of the MVVM design pattern, i.e. that you handle your application logic in the view model.

Make sure that the view model class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and provide change notifications as explained on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Perfect, that did it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it also possible to call a function of the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a INotifyPropertyChanged event on your view model, then bind it to the 'IsEnabled={Binding IsTextBoxEnabled}' attribute in your view template for the textbox.

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool _isTextBoxEnabled;
    public bool IsTextBoxEnabled
    {
        get { return _isTextBoxEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isTextBoxEnabled)
                _isTextBoxEnabled = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsTextBoxEnabled");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding}">
                <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsTextBoxEnabled}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` serves no purpose on that binding.